# Remove top taskbar of vmware when i switch to fullscreen

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

That taskbar in top of the screen really bothers me. i cant see the connection and internet icon for connecting to wireless. furthermore, i cant see the bluetooths icon too.

i wonder if if you can help me in orther to remove that taskbar from top of the screen on vmware workstaion.

Answer (score 0):

In VMware Workstation:

1. Select `Preferences` from the `Edit` menu
2. Select `Display` from the left pane
3. Deselect `Show toolbar edge when unpinned in full screen` checkbox

See [this thread](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/425173?start=0&tstart=0) for reference.

Comment: how can this be done in VMware player?